# Convert email to an image?

Tags: php

I am wondering how can I convert my website user's emails to images?

I have an ads site and I want to protect users emails by using this tool. I seen many websites that offer this task but I want to do it on site for each user email that is displayed.

Any clues?

I am using PHP to do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
    // get string
    $text = $_GET['text'];
} else {
    // set default
    $text = 'liame';
};
// reverse string
$text = strrev($text);
$textLength = strlen($text);
$textHeight = 10;

// create image handle
$image = ImageCreate($textLength*($textHeight-1),20);

// set colours
$backgroundColour = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255); // white
$textColour = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0); // black

// set text
ImageString($image,$textHeight,0,0,$text,$textColour);

// set correct header  
header('Content-type: image/png');

// create image
ImagePNG($image);
```

and then

```
$email = $row['email'];

<img src="image.php?text=<?php echo $email; ?>" alt="Hidden Email" />
```

but it doesn't work, the image shows as broken.

Comment: How much use is an image showing a reversed email address going to be? I'd close your website immediately if I saw that.

Comment: Also, I ran this code through [PHPTester](http://phptester.net/) (as most eval.in type testers online don't support GD) and it works fine (outputs "email"). Problem elsewhere...? Try removing your `header()` call and seeing if PHP is generating any errors.

Comment: Fun fact: `image.php?text=niet@example.com` is no "safer" for your users than `niet@example.com` is. This should be done inline, if at all.

Comment: I think using this methode is no useful solution against spam, because by parsing the source code a bot will still be able to find a valid email adress. I think you should replace the Email Get-Parameter with a database suffix or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "straight from DB" solution:

***Sidenote:*** I chose to use two columns with a `WHERE` clause, but you can change it.

Doing it the way you wanted to, well... the comments underneath your question speak for themselves.

You could either set it (this code) inside an `iframe` in the page you want it to show up in.

Sidenote:
***It cannot*** be an "include", because that will overwrite your page's content with the image's header.

Yes, I know and I am aware that **it** defeats the purpose, but you can also show it from an `img src` and linking to it, either to an `href` or `mailto:` <= **it** - I'm just outlining what your (additional) options are, should you want to use them in the future. Linking it to a form that people can fill out, will be a better way.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image_generator_file.php"></a>
```

*or,* just not linking it at all:

```
<img src="image_generator_file.php" border="0">
```

---

***Sidenote:*** `WHERE id = 1` can be changed to `WHERE id = $user_id` and populating it and fetched from DB. You would need to wrap it in quotes `WHERE id = '$user_id'` if it's VARCHAR and pre-define the variable ahead of time. I.e.: `$user_id = $row['email'];` for example.

**PHP/SQL:**

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php'; // Make sure connection is mysqli_ and not mysql_

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, email FROM your_table WHERE id = 1");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $email = $row['email'];

    }


    $text = $email;

    // reverse string
    //$text = strrev($text);

    $textLength = strlen($text);
    $textHeight = 10;

    // create image handle
    $image = ImageCreate($textLength*($textHeight-1),20);

    // set colours
    $backgroundColour = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255); // white
    $textColour = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0); // black

    // set text
    ImageString($image,$textHeight,0,0,$text,$textColour);

    // set correct header  
     header('Content-type: image/png');

    // create image
    ImagePNG($image);
```

---

For added styling, you can set a CSS class to the image:

```
<img src="image_generator_file.php" class="pad">
```

CSS:

```
.pad {
padding-top:3px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
background:#ffffff;
}
```